Placing a Custom LWC into a Block Element in Omniscript
I have a custom LWC element in my Omniscript. However, I am unable to place it under a Block element. I wonder what's the issue and if there is anyway for it to work?

Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read How to Ask. It would be useful to be able to see the configuration of your OmniScript if possible, for example whether the Block is nested or repeatable. Could you please [edit] your question to add more details.

In order to add custom LWC component, you need to go to the Build Tab and search for Custom Lightning Web Component. This will allow you to add a custom LWC.
Additionally ensure that the JS file of LWC has omniscript extension included like below:
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from "vlocity/omniscriptBaseMixin";
export default class yourcustomlwc extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement){ }

And the XML needs to have
<runtimeNamespace>namespace</runtimenamespace>
<isExposed>True</isExposed>



